# Angularjs. Access to variable in directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive

```
var chartDir = function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        stat: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        console.log(scope);
        return;
      }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<svg chart stat="stat"></svg>
```

So in this case I can see in console that scope has a property called `stat` (an array, not empty!)

Here is the screenshot...

[image]

But if I do `console.log( scope.stat )` then i get just `undefined`. I have the same directive in some other chart and it is working fine. But here I can not understand why I can't get access to `scope.stat`

UPD:
more html

```
<div class="chart-container container" ng-show="statLoaded">
  <div class="text col">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in stat | limitTo: middleIndex">
      <div class="color">
        <div class="sample" color-sample color="item.color"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="amount">
        {{ item.amount }}
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        {{ item.text }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <svg chart stat="stat"></svg>
  </div>
 ...
```

So I see all items and directive "color-sample" works good. So 'stat' is loaded. So, why 'color-sample' directive works and 'chart' doesen't?

Comment: Looks like the `stat` property on the directive's parent hasn't been set before your directive is executed. And by the time you look at the console window there has been enough time for the `stat` property to be set

Comment: ok. I understand about console. But how can I pass stat to derective. Close to this block I have another with 'stat' and it's loads perfectly well, so 'stat' is loaded and exists (in controller and should be passed to this derective). 
I also added scope.$watch(scope.stat, function () {.. to derective, but it's still undefined.
How can I render my derective when I get 'stat' loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is

```
scope.$watch(attr.stat, function () {
```

instead of

```
scope.$watch(scope.stat, function () {
```